# Setting JavaScript variable with click event for dynamic form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some `PHP` which outputs `JavaScript`. I need to set the `id` dynamically. The following code breaks on the 3rd line because of the use of the `i` variable. This I expect to be a simple problem with the quotation marks but I could be wrong.

```
$html .='$("#add").click(function (e) {';

    $html .= 'var i=0;';

    //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
    $html .='$("#items").append(\'<div><input name=\"input[]\" type=\"text\" id=\"itin_form_'+i+'\" /><button class=\"delete\">Delete</button></div>\'); i++; });';
```

Can anyone see why this code fails?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do it this way and not through JavaScript/jQuery directly ?

Comment: Yes, I'm having to return $html at the end of a function, I'd prefer to do it another way but looks like I'm going to be forced to do it like this.

Comment: @user1532669 I found the issue first. Anyway, glad that it got solved. Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
$html .= 'var i=0;';
$html .='$("#add").click(function (e) {';
 //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
$html .='$("#items").append(\'<div><input name="input[]" type="text" id="itin_form_\'+i+\'" /><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>\'); i++; });';
```

When escaped to Javascript it should return:

```
var i=0;
$("#add").click(function (e) {
    $("#items").append('<div><input name="input[]" type="text" id="itin_form_'+i+'" /><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>'); 
    i++; 
});
```

Comment: I'll help you even further. There is no need for escaping the double quotes, since they are in a string that's being defined with single quotes.

Comment: Yes, I understood that already and updated accordingly buddy. `:D` Check. :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, whenever you click, the value of `i` gets initialized to `0`. It is indeed a simple silly mistake. Your code gives you this result:

```
$("#add").click(function (e) {
    var i=0;
    $("#items").append('<div><input name="input[]" type="text" id="itin_form_'+i+'" /><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>'); 
    i++; 
});
```

But it supposed to have something like this:

```
var i = 0;
$("#add").click(function (e) {
    $("#items").append('<div><input name="input[]" type="text" id="itin_form_'+i+'" /><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>'); 
    i++; 
});
```

See the placement of `var i = 0;` above. So your code should be:

```
$html .= 'var i=0;';
$html .='$("#add").click(function (e) {';
 //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
$html .='$("#items").append(\'<div><input name="input[]" type="text\\" id=\"itin_form_\'+i+\'" /><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>\'); i++; });';
```

You don't need to escape `"` in the above code. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

There's many issues with your code to begin with:

#### Variable `var i=0` is declared inside the function so it's always getting reset and never going to increase over 1.

**Solution**: you have to declare it only once at the page load, e.g. in a script tag in your `<head>` section or inside a jquery document ready call. I showed an example below.

#### Please get rid of all these escape characters by using PHP [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

Here's an example `test.php` tested and working I created myself using your javascript code as-is (I just removed all the escape characters to make it more readable):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="items"></div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />

<?php

$str =
<<<'EOT'
<script>
/* Start of Nowdoc
   you can paste javascript code in here as-is!
*/
var i=0; // notice how I declared this outside of add.click
$("#add").click(function (e) {
    $("#items").append('<div><input name="input[]" type="text" id="itin_form_'+i+'" /><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>');
    i++;
}
);
/* End of Nowdoc */
</script>
EOT;


echo $str;

?>
```

Output:

[image]

#### Maybe you're just forgetting to include the jquery library.

Add this to your `<head>` section:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar: For other people that will fall on that answer on day and find something useful for themselves :)